# Why do PIL and matplotlib create completely different images here?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I was creating an image of something from an array and matplotlib can only give a certain "dpi" before the kernel crashes after you ask it (e.g. for a dpi=8000 plot, the kernel just dies instantly). I therefore decided to make the image with PIL - but it was completely messed up.

I've created an MCVE:

```py
a = np.zeros([5,5])
a[:,2] = 255
a = np.repeat(a[...,np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
```

If we put this through `matplotlib` with

```py
img = plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

We get this image:[image: Extremely simple expected plot.]

But if we use the analogous PIL code

```py
img = Image.fromarray(a, "RGB")
img.save("Stuff.png")
```

we get this image:

[image: Crazy image with weird colours.]

(The image here has been screen-shot and enlarged, because it is, in actuality, just 5x5 pixels)

Why is this?! Is this just a bug?!

EDIT: The question has now been resolved and thanks to this and a previous question, my computations are far quicker and more pythonic. As a thanks to SO, here's a screenshot of a 400 megapixel image of the Mandelbrot Set coloured based on the quadrant of C that a point Z ends up in just as it escapes that can now be computed in 2 minutes:

[image]

Comment: PIL expects HxWxC array, and you just pass [5,5]. Can you try to do `a = np.zeros([5,5,3])` instead?

Comment: I do pass a HxWxC array. That's what the 3 line in the initialisation of a does - othewise PIL would just reject a.

Comment: my bad, I missed something in plain sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 64 bit floating point values as input, since that is the default dtype for `np.zeros()`.
`fromarray()`'s ["RGB" mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) requires 3 x 8 bit pixels.

Try with:

```
img = Image.fromarray(a.astype(np.uint8), "RGB")
```